# How to correctly specify migration namespace classes in yii2?

Tags: yii2, migrate

could someone explain me how can I correctly specify my `modules migration namespaces`? As I see in the documentation, it's:

```
return [
'controllerMap' => [
    'migrate' => [
        'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
        'migrationNamespaces' => [
            'app\migrations', // Common migrations for the whole application
            'module\migrations', // Migrations for the specific project's module
            'some\extension\migrations', // Migrations for the specific extension
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

But there are no explanation in which file should I write the commands. I've tried it in config.php, as:

```
    'controllerMap' => [
    'migrate' => [
        'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
        'migrationNamespaces' => [
            'app\modules\adBoard\migrations',
        ],
```

But I don't know which controller class should I write. Could someone tell me in which file I have to specify it and how to specify it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to this documentation

> **Configuring Command Globally**
>
> Instead of entering the same option
>   values every time you run the migration command, you may configure it
>   once for all in the application configuration like shown below:

```
return [
     'controllerMap' => [
         'migrate' => [
             'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
             'migrationTable' => 'backend_migration',
         ],
     ], ];
```

> With the above configuration, each time you run the migration command, the backend_migration table will be used to record
>   the migration history. You no longer need to specify it via the
>   migrationTable command-line option.
>
> **Namespaced Migrations**
>
> Since 2.0.10 you can use namespaces for the
>   migration classes. You can specify the list of the migration
>   namespaces via migrationNamespaces. Using of the namespaces for
>   migration classes allows you usage of the several source locations for
>   the migrations. For example:

```
 return [
     'controllerMap' => [
         'migrate' => [
             'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
             'migrationNamespaces' => [
                 'app\migrations', // Common migrations for the whole application
                 'module\migrations', // Migrations for the specific project's module
                 'some\extension\migrations', // Migrations for the specific extension
             ],
         ],
     ], ];
```

this config should be placed in you console/config/main.php

but for namespaced  migration remeber that starting for 2.0.10

Answer (score 1):

depending on your yii2-template application (`basic` or `advanced`) the location of "console" specific settings are located in different directories.

For **basic** template, console fetch settings from `<app>/config/console.php` file.

And for **advanced** template, you should edit `<app>/console/config/main.php` file.

Remember that your settings for console will not affect web-settings, so if you want to register some component in the whole project, you have to duplicate it in both files.

P.S. I would like to add one more detail about **advanced** template, is that it has common setting for **frontend** and **backend** sub-apps, which is located in `<app>/common/config/main.php`, but those settings are not common with console commands.

Comment: Just tried to enter my mentioned commands to `console.php` file (because of the `basic` template), but didn't worked :( I cannot run my migration because of the namespace, when I delete it, it's working

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my experience with Yii2 namespaced migrations.

**Scenario**

1. I am using advanced template.
2. I have 100s of old migrations in `console/migrations` folder.
3. I have new extension which have namespaced migrations.
4. I have new migrations in old folder `console/migrations`.
5. I want to create future migrations with namespaces in new folder `console/migrations/namespaced`. I want to keep all old migrations intact which are located at `console/migrations`.

`console/config/main.php` configurations worked for me.

```
return [
'controllerMap' => [
    'migrate' => [
        'class' => \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::class,
        'migrationNamespaces' => [
            'console\migrations\namespaced',
            'yii\swiftsmser\migrations'
        ]
    ],
],
//.... more configurations
];
```

With above configurations, when I executed `yii migrate`, It includes all above mentioned folders.

*Note: To create new migration. Just make sure to use command like below.*

`yii migrate/create  console\\migrations\\namespaced\\DLTTemplatesForSMS`